# Merge two xml strings in java

Tags: java, sql, xml

I'm trying to merge/combine two xml strings that I got from parsing an object to XML using castor marshalling/unmarshalling. Here are the two XML strings that I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abc:abcResponse xmlns:abc="http://www.abc.com/schema/abcTransaction">
    <abc:code>0</abc:code>
    <abc:description>blah</abc:description>
</abc:abcResponse>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abc:abcRequest xmlns:abc="http://www.abc.com/schema/abcTransaction">
    <abc:id>99999</abc:id>
    <abc:idString>abc</abc:idString>
</abc:abcRequest>
```

I want to be able to combine these two strings into one so I can insert this into my database (MSSQL) column that has data type XML. I tried using the solution suggested from this link [java merge two xml strings in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208241/java-merge-two-xml-strings-in-java), but it doesn't seem to recognize it as a valid XML string since no records were inserted into the database table, and there's this error in my console:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: XML parsing: line 1, character 12,   text/xmldecl not at the beginning of input
```

If I insert either of these strings separately into the database column then a new record will be added just fine.

Anyone has a good idea as to how to do this properly? Much thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [java merge two xml strings in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208241/java-merge-two-xml-strings-in-java)

Comment: this is not a duplicate since what was done there cannot be applied to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create something like the following ("abcTransaction" is a wild guess).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abc:abcTransaction xmlns:abc="http://www.abc.com/schema/abcTransaction">
    <abc:abcRequest>
        <abc:id>99999</abc:id>
        <abc:idString>abc</abc:idString>
    </abc:abcRequest>
    <abc:abcResponse>
        <abc:code>0</abc:code>
        <abc:description>blah</abc:description>
    </abc:abcResponse>
</abc:abcTransaction>
```

Maybe even leaving out the xmlns and "abc:" parts.

Comment: Thanks, using this and the substring trick worked, thank you guys!