# It is possible to read the complete content of a xml files inside a folder with java?

Tags: java, xml

It is possible to read the complete content of a xml files inside a folder with java?

My code is:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();      
dbf.setValidating(false);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = db.parse(new FileInputStream(new 
File("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\eclipse-workspace\\XMLExamples2\\")));

Element element = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("composite").item(0);

// Adds a new attribute. If an attribute with that name is already present 
// in the element, its value is changed to be that of the value parameter
element.setAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
instance");
element.setAttribute("xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "v1_6.xsd");
```

I'm just able to read and manipulate single files when it put the name after ...\XMLExample2\

Comment: Well yes - so loop over all the files in the folder, and load one at a time.

Comment: Use [File#listFiles()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) and parse each one

Comment: You have to read the file from the directory in a loop like in the below example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/how-do-i-iterate-through-the-files-in-a-directory-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't process the content of multiple XML files as a unique document.

But you may list the XML files then process each `File` from the list :

```
String xmlDir = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\eclipse-workspace\\XMLExamples2";
File[] files = new File(xmlDir).listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File folder, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml");
        }
    });

for(File file : files){

    Document doc = db.parse(file);

    Element element = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("composite").item(0);

    // etc...

}
```

Comment: i get this error code. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at AddAttribute_test.main(AddAttribute_test.java:37) line 37 is the first setAttribute

Comment: Try to  print the name of the file (`file.getName()`) and check if its content is as expected .

Comment: you mean in the parse section? Document doc = db.parse();

Comment: Well the `setAttribute` line shouldn't give you a nullpointer, except if `element` is null. And yes I meant print the file name at the beginning of the loop, to know which one is currently processed .

Comment: element is null. but why? i defined element in the line above: Element element = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("composite").item(0);

Comment: like this? Document doc = db.parse(file.getName());

Comment: No I just meant to print the name like `System.out.println(file.getName())` so that you know on which file the loop is currently .

Comment: ah yeah. ofc sorry

Comment: thats wired. he gives me .project back.

Comment: You should filter to get only the XML files, see last edit .

Comment: ok the Filefilter is working, but access is denied to the other .xml files.

Answer (score -1):

Each file is a seperate document. So, if you aren't trying to read them as a single document, then all you need to do is grab a list of files in that folder using the `File` class' `listFiles()` method. You can then loop over each file in the folder and process them accordingly.

If you do want to treat it as a single XML document: you will need to merge the files together first, and then process it. There are a number of ways that can be done. You may want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648471/merge-two-xml-files-in-java) for a couple ideas.